# combining model object with related objects as attribute

Tags: django

I have 2 related models, say

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)


class PersonPicture(models.Model):
    image = ImageField(...)
    person = ForeignKey(Person)
```

I send to a template `context['persons']=Person.objects.all()`
and access related manager.

```
{% for p in persons %}
    {{ p.name }}
    {{ p.personpicture_set.all.0.image }}
{% endfor %}
```

This `{{ p.personpicture_set.all.0.image }}` generates one query for every item in for cycle.

Is there a way to comine related to the 'Person' images in the person model so there would be only one query from `Person.objects.all()`. in the template i could `{{ p.images_custom_attr.0 }}` and it would generate no queries.

Comment: Read about "prefetch_related()".

Comment: thanks, that seems to be exactly what i need.

Comment: Actually, for a `ForeignKey` relationship like this you want `select_related`, maybe with a limit to only follow the `person` relationship instead - that does the join in the database instead of in Python, which will generally be faster.  `prefetch_related` is able to follow more types of relationships than `select_related`, but when you can use `select_related` you should at least profile the different options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select_related()` or `prefetch_related()`. As for the difference, from [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) -

> `select_related()` follows foreign keys as far as possible. If you have
>   the following models:
>
> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class City(models.Model):
>     # ...
>     pass
>
> class Person(models.Model):
>     # ...
>     hometown = models.ForeignKey(City)
>
> class Book(models.Model):
>     # ...
>     author = models.ForeignKey(Person) ...then a call to
> ```
>
> `Book.objects.select_related().get(id=4)` will cache the related Person
>   and the related City

And

> `select_related` works by creating a SQL join and including the fields
>   of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason,
>   `select_relate`d gets the related objects in the same database query.
>   However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from
>   joining across a ‘many’ relationship, select_related is limited to
>   single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.
>
> `prefetch_related`, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each
>   relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to
>   prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done
>   using `select_related`, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one
>   relationships that are supported by `select_related`.